# Decidability of linear equation about Sine and Cosine

Tags: decidability

Given integers $n,d$, and rational numbers $a_i,b_i,l_{i,j},s_{i,j}$ for $1\leq i\leq d$, $1\leq j\leq n$, we are considering the following equation
$$
\sum_{i} [a_i \sin(\sum l_{i,j}\theta_j)+b_i \cos(\sum s_{i,j}\theta_j)]=0.
$$
The question is to ask whether there are $\theta_j\in\mathbb{R}$
satisfy the above equation.

Is this problem decidable? If so, what does the algorithm look like?

Comment: Dividing the $\theta_j$ by an integer, we can assume that $l_{ij}$ and $s_{ij}$ are integers, in which case this becomes an algebraic equation in $x_j:=\sin(\theta_j)$ and $y_j:=\cos(\theta_j)$, which, by Tarski's theorem on the decidability of real-closed fields / semialgebraic geometry, is decidable. This can probably be improved into something at least remotely usable. But I wonder, do you really mean to have $1$ equation in $n$ unknowns?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thanks! That is exactly what I want. Would it become faster if we know that the left hand side is always greater than 0, the question is still to ask whether 0 is achievable, more efficiently?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much more than what I already wrote, but maybe you can have a look at Dumitrescu's book *Positive Trigonometric Polynomials and Signal Processing Applications* (2d ed 2017) in which I found some results concerning related problems.

Comment: @ Gro-Tsen  Thanks!

Comment: @Gro-Tsen By the way, is it still decidable for inequality?

Comment: Yes: any statement that can be reduced to boolean combinations of polynomial equalities or inequalities over the reals, with arbitrary quantifiers (over the reals or, of course, intervals of reals), is decidable: this is essentially Tarski's theorem I was alluding to.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thanks.